# Netbeans fails to deploy to Tomcat 7, works with Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, tomcat7

I have been using Netbeans with Tomcat 6.0.37 for a few weeks now without issue. Today I installed Tomcat 7.0.40 and changed the Home folder as such.

When I click run in netbeans I get the following:

```
In-place deployment at /Users/sean/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/build/web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2F6q%2Fwn580_m52f14dh0r5j1zm0v00000gn%2FT%2Fcontext1472679556924624209.xml&path=/WebApplication1
http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2F6q%2Fwn580_m52f14dh0r5j1zm0v00000gn%2FT%2Fcontext1472679556924624209.xml&path=/WebApplication1
/Users/sean/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)
```

The server log doesn't show anything helpful as far as I can tell, but here it is:

```
Jun 11, 2013 3:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 11, 2013 3:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 11, 2013 3:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@6e9b86ea')
```

The build-impl.xml:1033 is:

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
     <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

If I change the Tomcat Home folder back to version 6 it all works again. This leads me to believe it's a tomcat issue but I can't figure it out.

I did find a file local_access_log.[date].txt had the following, is it a clue?

```
[my ip] - - [11/Jun/2013:15:27:54 -0700] "GET /manager/deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2F6q%2Fwn580_m52f14dh0r5j1zm0v00000gn%2FT%2Fcontext1472679556924624209.xml&path=/WebApplication1 HTTP/1.1" 404 1549
```

Comment: you can add your update as an answer and accept it so that people find more easily the solution to such an issue

Comment: As a new user it made me wait a day to answer it. Now another day to mark it as correct :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent several hours today with this and find a solution minutes after posting here.

In Netbeans I had to delete Tomcat from the list of servers then manually add it back with all the same information. Netbeans must save details about the server the first and only time it connects.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, however, this definitely hasn't resolved anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue too. But for me, the problem was that I had the proxy enabled in my NetBeans setting. I just disabled it and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks man, this saved my day. Had the same issue and after disabling the proxy in Netbeans deplyoing works.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem in different version of netbeans i did all about unistalling the IDE or Jdk
and every thing that you try to solved and all googling this problem a lot 
as i try to solve this problem with go to server log and try to read the first error that you have after the first error you solve this error will be fix.
in my j2ee program the error was in my struts.xml and web.xml config that related to action class !
when the netbeans can't find the class of action class coz of wrong addressing give error 
 " the module has not been deployed see the server log for more detail "
build.xml:1079 , 596

i have lots error number with this issue and now fixed!!!!!!!!!!!

just try to lookup in config of struts.xml and web.xml
and context.xml !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial attempt is not working. To set up integration IDE (NetBeans) needs to know how to deploy developed apps. This is usually done by setting up roles and credentials in your Tomcat installation (CATALINA_HOME or CATALINA_USER). Going through the wizard did this setup for you. You can also check how it is configured if you open properties for this server (Ctrl-5 to open Services tab, select server under Servers node, open its properties using context menu there).

BTW: you can have more Tomcat instances registered in your NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late but your comment:

> I did find a file local_access_log.[date].txt had the following, is it a clue?

is indeed a clue. Netbeans tries to deploy using tomcat's manager. But when a "GET /manager/deploy?config..." returns a 404 that means the manager isn't installed in the webapps folder.
I just encountered the same problem, installing the manager (back) in place solved it :)